# Oscmax "Generated" Pages Missing After Move

Tags: php, oscommerce

## BACKGROUND

I am an [Oscmax](http://www.oscmax.com/) noob, who is trying to make simple changes to templates. The system I have recently inherited was not placed into version control, nor did it have it's customizations documented in any way. My goal is to clone oscmax, it's existing database and all configuration to a local machine, so that I may put it into version control, make changes to the test system, test, then deploy in a safe and sane manner.

## REMOTE SYSTEM

Oscmax v2.5 on a centos 6.4 system.

## LOCAL SYSTEM

Oscmax v2.5 on centos 6.4.

## Process Leading Up to Problem

1. Backed up database to local host.
2. Set up with oscmax user with correct permissions, testing with command-line to assure proper connection.
3. Used rsync command **rsync -avz -e ssh --progress --include ".*" --exclude "path/to/ups_module/tmpfiles" username@hostname.com:/var/www/html/ .** <-- note included local directory.
4. Altered includes/configure.php to point to localhost.
5. Altered /includes/configure.php to point to localhost.
6. Using **sudo chown -R :apache**, changed ownership of transferred files.

## Expected

Oscmax to display all "generated" pages properly.

Oscmax to allow administrator login.

## Observed

All static files are displaying properly.

Endpoints generated by oscmax it's self are not found.

#### Example of Success

```
http://localhost/index.php?cPath=123
```

returns the expected page

#### Example of Failure

```
http://localhost/synthetics-c-4.html
```

results in a 404.

Admin links are generated in the same way as the second example, thus they are non-functional. Any suggestions that require use of the admin interface will not work by definition and will not be accepted as an answer, with a polite explanation why.

Am I missing a basic concept, here? Glad to supply any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when you copied the files over with rsync it missed the hidden files

Make sure you run the command like the following:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --progress user@source-server:/source/to/copy/from/ /path/to/destination/
```

make sure you have trailing slashes on your directories as this can cause problems.

Comment: No dice. I also tried adding the --include switch with ".*" as target. None were transferred. Is there a reference for hidden files that I need to check?

Comment: Thanks [Ben Rowe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/123429/ben-rowe). I appreciate the effort. I'll post any fix I discover here, if the question isn't stifled.

Answer (score 0):

The problems were:

1. not having mod_rewrite enabled
2. not having

   AccessFileName .htaccess

explicitly set in httpd.conf, where the original developer wanted them.

Here is a [nice, quick explanation](http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/) of differences/gotchas vis. setting up mod_rewrite rules in httpd.conf vs. .htaccess, which helped to clear it up in my head.

The takeaway? Sometimes you have to clone things a step at a time.